# numpy with mypy: indexing NDArray returns Any type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mypy

Is it possible to index `numpy` arrays are receive at least the same type?

Running the following code through `mypy` reveals the following types:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

a = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int64)
reveal_type(a)  # numpy.ndarray[Any, Any]

sub_a = a[:1]
reveal_type(sub_a)  # Any

b: NDArray[np.int64] = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int64)
reveal_type(b)  # numpy.ndarray[Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.signedinteger[numpy.typing._64Bit]]]

sub_b = b[:1]
reveal_type(sub_b)  # Any
```

Thanks.